# Is there a way for a mysqli connection to stay open across files and functions (LAMP)?

Tags: php, mysqli, lamp

I have an index.php and a functions.php.

The index.php does not make connections to the database but uses functions from functions.php that connect all to the same database.

The functions start with

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('***', '***', '***', '***');
[...]
$mysqli -> close();
```

As the app grows there are more and more functions which call one other and I'm thinking there must be a better method than constantly opening and closing connections.

Comment: Of course you can make it a global and have it work. What have you tried that doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Read this --> http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Comment: @shamittomar: The article you link to talks about persistent connections, which is *a different thing entirely* from what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Jon, a persistent connection is a connection which "stays open across files and functions". What I really wanted to point out was that you do not need persistent connections AKA "connection that stay open across files and functions (LAMP)".

Comment: @shamittomar: A persistent connection is a connection which stays open *across HTTP requests*. http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: @jon Thanks, is works now, I had a $mysqli -> close(); leftover in one of the functions which made me believe global wouldn't work on $mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using classes?

Maybe put the MySQL connection statement in the ctor and using a class member to hold the mysqli handle?

Comment: Ah... You again, Col. Shrapnel. *"I do not press closevote buttons."* Says your profile. Is that so.

What's wrong with reusing a database connection, instead of constantly connecting and disconnecting? Have you read the question?